# Regex to mask special character password in files

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I want to remove or mask password from some confidential files. I am using following syntax and it works with simple password like alphabets and numbers base password but doesn't working with special character password like !@#$%^ . Does anyone know how to match special character in regex. Here what i am using for simple password.

```
sed -i 's/password="[0-9A-Za-z]\+"/password="XXXXXXXX"/g' server.xml
```

Comment: How are the quote characters escaped in the file? Is it with backslash (Eg. `password="My\"pass"`) or using double quotes (Eg. `password="My""pass"` ), or something else?

Comment: @awoodland: Not necessarily (but most likely :P) . I *could* be a password hash stored there? Let's hope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regexp instead. Are they allowed to have " in the password? Then you might need some more modifications.

```
sed -i 's/password="[^"]+"/password="XXXXXXXX"/g' server.xml
```

Comment: Hehe, I take it your problem was solved? Since it is an XML-file, I assume "-characters are escaped with &quot; and in that case the above regexp will work fine. But remember, there are often better ways to work with XML-files than regexp.